# Is there a way to create a hotkey to print a specific string in xcode?

Tags: xcode, comments, standards

Is there a way to create a hotkey to print a specific string in xcode?
For example if "H" is my hotkey, every time I click "H" it should paste "Hello" on my editor. 
This would help when inserting standard fixed comments when coding. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do it with Xcode code snippets. First you need to create a content (your comment or code or both). Select your content by dragging mouse on it. Release your mouse then click again on the selected part of text for a second. While holding, your mouse cursor symbol will change to the pointer symbol - drag this content to code snippets library. Xcode will create new code snipped for you. It will be placed at the bottom of all snippets in snippets library with the name "My Code Snippet". Double click it. Then press "Edit" button. Name it in the field "Title". Write summary you want. Choose platform "All" or "iOS" or "OS X". Select add completion shortcut for example "hello" for "//hello comment". Once you've done with all changes press "Done" button. Every time you will write "hello" Xcode will show a pop up with snippet title you have created. Select it and press "Enter" key and your comment will be placed right there where you wrote "hello".

Animated gif shows how you can do this:

[image: How to use snippets]

Comment: Hi Thankyou for the help. The drag and drop works fine. However the part when I write the completion shortcut does not work. In fact xcode crashed evrytime I tried to make changes to the code snippet!

Comment: Strange, because it's the main purpose of snippets to create shortcuts and to make our lives easier. Maybe I wrote something not exactly right so you can watch this video and see how it needs to be done [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGFSm0Zm2l4). And if you liked my answer please vote up on it ;) Actually I don't know what makes to crash your xcode, but it must work the way I showed it to you. if you'll find what was wrong and why your xcode crashed, please provide this info here.